# After float images, need to be centered in div

Tags: css, html

I've tried many times and it couldn't work at all. I need the float images in the centered inside the div. So I don't need to do padding and margin. It will be automatically nice when I put another images.

HTML

```
<div class="section-global">
    <p class="red"> HELLO </p>
    <p>
        <ul class="image-global">
            <li>
                <img src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" />
                <p> ABC </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" />
                <p> ABC </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" />
                <p> ABC </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" />
                <p> ABC </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section-global {
    margin:10px 0;
    border:1px solid #F63;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.section-global p {
    padding:10px;
}

.image-global {
    text-align:center;
}

.image-global li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.image-global img {
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

and here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d2rhR/1/). Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you want using `display:inline-block` with `float`?you can simply remove `float` and that's work and centered.but maybe your question is another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to float the list items left if you have used `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`.

If I am correct, this is what you want, right?

**http://jsfiddle.net/d2rhR/2/**

Just removed the float on

```
.image-global li {

    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the one I want. I thought I need to add float since the images are floating, but it's not necessary. No wonder it's not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take away `float:left;` in `.image-global li` and it will be done.

So it will be this:

```
.image-global li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The `display:inline-block;` will still give the desired outcome and will also center like you want.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/g2LMt/)

Comment: i think he don't want do it, he looking for a way image centered within `float`. and he know that's centered if remove `float`

Comment: It shouldn't matter that he uses `display:inline-block;` because it'll be the same outcome? @Radian

Comment: maybe have problem with old `ie`.`inline-block` not working on old ie version like `ie6`

Answer (score 0):

You should use only `display: inline-block;` and remove `float: left;` on your `.image-global li` class.

I have also added negative margin to close the gaps.

```
.image-global li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d2rhR/3/)**

Comment: I don't need margin, it's not necessary. It won't be nice when u add another image again.