# Images float inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with images. The images are not floating, but it does work in the center. However, i want the images floating and center of the div.. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="middle-align">
    <div id="gallery-left">
        <div class="gallery-left-middle">
            <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" /></a> </p>
            <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" /></a> </p>
            <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" /></a> </p>
            <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="assets/images/welcome.jpg" /></a> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery-left-middle {text-align:center;}
#gallery-left img{float:none;display:inline-block;width:180px;height:180px;}
```

I followed this question : [Question solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036851/after-float-images-need-to-be-centered-in-div). But it still doesn't work.

The problem is the images are not floating, but it's in the center. Any ideas?

Comment: See the w3cschools on positioning and floating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `p` is block element and it will automatically fill `width` of his parent `div` and because `img` has `text-align:center`, it is in center of that `p` element.
If you want to have those images floated, you can try set `display:inline-block` on those `p` elements instead of `img` elements.

```
.gallery-left-middle {text-align:center;}
.gallery-photo {display: inline-block;} 
img{width:180px;height:180px;}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p6TrR/1/)